# Restoring an Exchange 2007 SP3 GRT backup from Backup Exec 12 yields error E000848C

Tags: exchange-2007, backupexec

I am trying to restore an individual folder from an Exchange 2007 GRT backup, and the restore is failing with error code E000848C.

The setup is a Windows Server 2008 Standard x64 machine running Exchange 2007 SP3, and a Windows Server 2008 Standard x64 machine running Backup Exec 12.5.

Both servers were updated with the latest Windows Updates on Sunday just passed.

The backup in question is a nightly, full Information Store backup to disk.

I have tried:

- Ensuring the Backup Exec service account is a Domain Administrator, Exchange Organization Administrator, Local Administrator on both the Exchange and Backup Exec servers.
- Granting Full Access over the mailbox in question to the service account.
- Creating a mailbox for the account and ensuring it has a unique name, that it is populated in the Global Address Book and that I have both sent and received an email via OWA.
- Installing the Exchange Management Tools for EX2007SP3 on the Backup Exec server.
- Uninstalling and then reinstalling the Remote Agent for Windows Servers and ensuring it publishes itself to the Media Server.
- Pinging between the servers to confirm there is no layer 1 fault (!).
- Rebooting the Backup Exec server.
- Restoring a single message - which failed.
- Restoring a single folder - which failed.
- Restoring from another mailbox - which failed.
- Ensuring both servers have a staging directory, C:\Temp\, which the service account has access to.

I have had a read through the Debug log from Backup Exec and the only thing that looks important, to me, is "ERROR: 10 Error: Invalid device". I've been through the Backup Exec site and not found any solution that has worked for me.

The interesting thing is that when I run the "Symantec Help" utility, it claims that the Backup Exec account is not a member of the Local Admin group, not a member of the Domain Admin group and not a member of the Exchange Organization Admins group. However, when I query against AD, I am told the opposite:

```
PS Z:\> Get-QADMemberOf

cmdlet Get-QADMemberOf at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity: DOMAIN\BACKUPEXEC

Name                           Type            DN
----                           ----            --
Domain Users                   group           CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=s...
Exchange Organization Admin... group           CN=Exchange Organization Admi...
Domain Admins                  group           CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=...
```

All servers have the "Domain Admins" group as members of the local Administrators group, and I have also added the BACKUPEXEC account as a local Administrator explicitly, on both the Exchange and Backup Exec servers.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be occuring?

If it helps, I've posted a copy of the backup log below. I have anonymised the server names, account names and DNS names for security.

```
***************************************************************************
*****                  SGMon log for \\BACKUPSERVER                       *****
***************************************************************************
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpConnectEx: 'BACKUPSERVER' resolves to the local machine itself. So, we will try and connect to a loopback address ...
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpConnectEx : Control Connection information: A connection was established between end-points [::1]:58529 and [::1]:10000.
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3464] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpRun: Control connection accepted : connection established between end-points [::1]:10000 and [::1]:58529
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP version 3 connection CONNECTED
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector::AuthenticateClient(): Using Default Account for proxy Authentication
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000118] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_ACTJOBEX_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000119] [Debug] VSN is an ADD
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000120] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000121] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_SCHJOB_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000122] [Debug] VSN is a MODIFY
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 -1 Client requested key (1364394032).
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:39 [0018] [0000123] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 01 Server Configuration: Client added: 8
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 -1 Client 'BACKUPSERVER' connected('','DOMAIN\BACKUPEXEC'): 0xbab4ba0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPEngine::SetupNDMPConnection(): Using the system default logon account
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECryptoInit: BECrypto non-FIPS mode successfully enabled.
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECryptoInit: BECrypto non-FIPS mode successfully enabled.
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 BELogonUser: beclass::IsThisMe() returned error: 87
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 LogonType set = [LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH][0x4]
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 LogonUser(LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH-0x4) success
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Successfully impersonated DOMAIN\BACKUPEXEC
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 WhoAmI( ) reports: DOMAIN\BACKUPEXEC
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 01 Server Configuration: Client removed: 7
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 -1 Client 'BACKUPSERVER' Disconnected:0xbab4ba0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 PDI data store server(BACKUPSERVER) supports PDI
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector::EndConnection(): Data Server = BACKUPSERVER
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 FS supports PDI.
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Enter RestoreMessageHandler::SetTargetDeviceName
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40   OS ID is [0x46]
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40   Target OS ID is [0x46]
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3984] 03/27/13 14:17:40 @@@@@@@MyCloseSocket called with sockfd = 1868(0x74c)    retval = 0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40   Device Subtype is [0x2]
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: in : inFamilyGuid({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}), familyId(1115360205), setNum(1)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Get a Connection from Pool : Size(3)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: status(0) connectServerComponent : in (0) -- current 0
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ValidateConnection :  1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Input Parameters for BackupSet_ByResource_View : [1]({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}),[3](1)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: SELECT * FROM ImageObjectView where 1=1  AND MediaFamilyGuid = {F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}  AND ImageNumber = 1  ORDER BY  MediaFamilyGuid  ,  ImageNumber  ,  MediaNumber
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Number of records returned: 1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: out : devName = \\EMAILSERVER.domain.local\Microsoft Information Store\MX01 First Storage Group
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ReleaseConnection ...
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Reset connection ...
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40   Queried Device: \\EMAILSERVER.domain.local\Microsoft Information Store\MX01 First Storage Group
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40   Setting target path: []
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Exit SetTargetDeviceName - deviceName: [\\EMAILSERVER.domain.local\Microsoft Information Store\MX01 First Storage Group]
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ValidatePDILocation: Validating PDI location: [E:\Backup Sets\EMAILSERVER IS Daily\IMG002071]. Temp path: [C:\TEMP]
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: in : imageGuid({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13})
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Get a Connection from Pool : Size(3)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: status(0) connectServerComponent : in (0) -- current 0
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ValidateConnection :  1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Input Parameters for Image_Fragments_View : [26]({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13})
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: SELECT * FROM ImageObjectView where 1=1  AND ImageGUID = {F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}  ORDER BY  MediaFamilyGuid  ,  ImageNumber  ,  MediaNumber
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Number of records returned: 1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ReleaseConnection ...
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:40]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Reset connection ...
PVLSVR:   [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [1532] 03/27/13 14:17:40.645 PvlEntityDatabase::QueryEntity()

            ParentEntityType = NULL_ENTITY_TYPE

            ParentEntityGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

            EntityType = DEVICE_ENTITY_TYPE

            EntityGuid = {95700489-EB21-4B0D-899A-712296779488}

            EntityName = ""

            EntityFlags = 0x00000000
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Media Label: IMG002071
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 12 AdammAdminBO::Get() - Parent = NULL , Entity = MEDIA
PVLSVR:   [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [1532] 03/27/13 14:17:40.645 PvlEntityDatabase::QueryEntity()

            ParentEntityType = NULL_ENTITY_TYPE

            ParentEntityGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

            EntityType = MEDIA_ENTITY_TYPE

            EntityGuid = {F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}

            EntityName = ""

            EntityFlags = 0x00000000
PVLSVR:   [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [1532] 03/27/13 14:17:40.645 PvlEntityDatabase::QueryEntity() : SUCCESS!
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:40 12 AdammAdminBO::Get() - hr = 0x0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Trying to create backup BSD \\EMAILSERVER.domain.local\Microsoft Information Store\MX01 First Storage Group for PDI restore
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Failed to Load AllowExcludes key, We will update DR file evenif there are userExcludes. Error: 5
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector:SetupConnection(): Data Server = BACKUPSERVER
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 Could not resolve the "bews-ndmp" or the "ndmp" service, error code: 10109, using port 10000
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpConnectEx: 'BACKUPSERVER' resolves to the local machine itself. So, we will try and connect to a loopback address ...
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpConnectEx : Control Connection information: A connection was established between end-points [::1]:58533 and [::1]:10000.
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [3464] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpRun: Control connection accepted : connection established between end-points [::1]:10000 and [::1]:58533
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP version 3 connection CONNECTED
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector::AuthenticateClient(): Using SSPI authentication with SLA/DLA as a fallback
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector::ConnectAuthUseSSPIasDefault(): Attempting SSPI authentication...
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext status 0x00090312 in 0 out 51
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: AcceptSecurityContext status 0x00090312 in 51 out 192
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext status 0x00000000 in 192 out 88
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: AcceptSecurityContext status 0x00000000 in 88 out 0
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: Security Package Name: NTLM
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: client authenticated as BACKUPEXEC
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 CreateAnonymousSID: sid is S-1-5-7
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 IsUserAnonymous() returns FALSE
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMP_SSPI: client authenticated with server
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 NDMPAgentConnector::ConnectAuthUseSSPIasDefault(): SSPI authentication success.
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpdDataConnect: RAWS is attempting data connection on

    IP : 10.10.10.22

    Port : 20658
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:40 ndmpdDataConnect : Data Connection information: A connection was established between end-points 10.10.10.37:58535 and 10.10.10.22:20658.
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 PDIRestoreBSDProcessor::EstablishPDIDataConnection() - data connection established successfully.
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:40] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:40 PDIRestoreBSDProcessor::ProcessPDIDataTransfer: Starting data transfer between EMAILSERVER.domain.local and BACKUPSERVER
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 ERROR: 10 Error: Invalid device
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Enter RestoreMessageHandler::GetMachineName
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: in : inFamilyGuid({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}), familyId(1115360205), setNum(1)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Get a Connection from Pool : Size(3)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: status(0) connectServerComponent : in (0) -- current 0
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ValidateConnection :  1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Input Parameters for BackupSet_ByResource_View : [1]({F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}),[3](1)
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: SELECT * FROM ImageObjectView where 1=1  AND MediaFamilyGuid = {F0835925-89FE-47C5-BB82-DDFDD3B78F13}  AND ImageNumber = 1  ORDER BY  MediaFamilyGuid  ,  ImageNumber  ,  MediaNumber
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: Number of records returned: 1
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]: out : devName = \\EMAILSERVER.domain.local\Microsoft Information Store\MX01 First Storage Group
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  ReleaseConnection ...
BECAT:    [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     BECAT : [03/27/13 14:17:41]:[3908:2404]:[3]:  Reset connection ...
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Exit GetMachineName - Machine name: [EMAILSERVER.domain.local]
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 NDMPAgentConnector::EndConnection(): Data Server = BACKUPSERVER
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:41 NDMP_SSPI: reverted to user SYSTEM
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:41 @@@@@@@MyCloseSocket called with sockfd = 2020(0x7e4)    retval = 0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 NDMPAgentConnector::EndConnection(): Data Server = EMAILSERVER.domain.local
BEREMOTE: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4936] 03/27/13 14:17:41 @@@@@@@MyCloseSocket called with sockfd = 1868(0x74c)    retval = 0
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Removing 'Restore 00076' from status update list
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Updating status for: 'Restore 00076' (0x18 0xB)
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Status for: 'Restore 00076' updated
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Merging of BE / VSR Job Logs not necessary for this Type of Job
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Ending job 'Restore 00076' with error status (-536836980)
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:41 17 JobManager::HandleEndJob() called
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 -1 ActiveState::doEndEvent( ): 'Restore 00076'
BENGINE:  [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [2404] 03/27/13 14:17:41 Job thread terminating
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 17 JobManager::DoJobCompletionTasks(Restore 00076): GetFinalJobStatus()=6
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 17 JobManager::DoJobCompletionTasks() Handling normal JOB_STATE_ERROR
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:41 01 Server Configuration: Client removed: 6
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [4524] 03/27/13 14:17:41 -1 Client 'BACKUPSERVER' Disconnected:0xbab4cc0
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 17 JobManager::DoJobCompletionTasks() Finished building JOB_STATE_ERROR message
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 18 Alert Job Failed, Notify: No, EventLog: Yes, Trap: No
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:41] [0000]     [3660] 03/27/13 14:17:41 -1 ActiveState::doEndEvent( ): CJobManager::DoJobCompletionTasks() returned 0x0
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000124] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_ALERT_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000125] [Debug] VSN is an ADD
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000126] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000127] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_COMPJOB_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000128] [Debug] VSN is an ADD
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000129] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000130] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_ACTJOBEX_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000131] [Debug] VSN is a REMOVE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:42] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:41 [0018] [0000132] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     [3156] 03/27/13 14:17:44 17 JobManager: Sending History Update VSN, count:1.
BESERVER: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     [3156] 03/27/13 14:17:44 17 CJobManagerBO::Query QUERY_JOBSETUP_MONITOR
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000133] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_JOBHIST_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000134] [Debug] VSN is a MODIFY
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000135] [Debug] No VSN payload - do a reset
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000136] [Debug] VSN added to queues
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000137] [Info] VSN received: type = VSN_TYPE_SCHJOB_UPDATE
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000138] [Debug] VSN is a MODIFY
BKUPEXEC: [03/27/13 14:17:45] [0000]     03/27/13 14:17:44 [0018] [0000139] [Debug] VSN added to queues
```

Comment: Are the Exchange Management tools on the backup server the same version as on the Exchange server?

Comment: I'm unsure on the exact version numbers but the BE server has Exchange 2007 SP3 tools installed, and the Exchange server is Exchange 2007 SP3?

Comment: To be sure, open the EMC on the Exchange server and on the Backup server and see if the version number matches in Help|About.

Comment: The mail server shows Exchange Server 2007 version 08.03.0083.000 - the BE server shows the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this configuration is not supported with any version lower than Backup Exec 2010  see http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH135234

"Exchange 2007 Service Pack 3 (SP3) is supported starting with Backup Exec versions 2010 and 2010 R2."

Backup Exec Software Compatibility List
http://entsupport.symantec.com/umi/V-269-1

I highly recommend upgrading to Backup Exec 2010R3 sp1

Thanks,
Lenora

Comment: Backup Exec 12 is < BE 2010?! I suppose the 20... missing is the clue...